# Arranging Vigenere Cipher into columns

Tags: encryption, vigenere

As I understand if you arrange a Vigenere cipher into columns you can use the Index Of Coincidence to find out the key length. 
I'm struggling to write an Algorithm that would take a piece of text and arrange it into columns.

For example - 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Would return this if the period is 2 - 
1,3,5,7,9
2,4,6,8,10

and perform an IOC test on each of these strings

IF the period is 3 - 
1,4,7,10
2,5,8
3,6,9

and perform an IOC test on each of these strings

Etc etc. 
I've constructed an IOC test however I'm struggling to think of an algorithm to split the text up into collumns, any tips on how to think more like a computer scientist and construct algorithms like this?

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the key length, it's pretty trivial. If you don't know the key length, you have to guess it by entropy. Here is an example in Python for instance:

```
if you_dont_know_key_length:
    key_length = find_key_length_by_entropy(ciphertext)

columns = [ciphertext[i::key_length] for i in xrange(key_length)]
```

Any language should basically have the same construct (pick every *n*-th element in the ciphertext)